# Can i mute the microphone from mediadevices?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, record, voice-recording

i recording users video and voice with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` there is no problem but while recording video i don't want to hear microphone voice can i mute the microphone?

i tried this `stream.getAudioTracks()[0].muted`

here is my code piece

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true, audio: {
                echoCancellation: true,
                noiseSuppression: true,
                sampleRate: 44100
            }
        })
            .then(stream => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
                stream.getAudioTracks()[0].muted //doesn't work
                var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)

                start.addEventListener('click', _ => {
                    mediaRecorder.start()
                    console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
                })

                stop.addEventListener('click', _ => {
                    mediaRecorder.stop()
                    console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
                    stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                        track.stop();
                    })
                })

                mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', _ => {
                    let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type': 'video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus' });
                    let videoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly - you want to record the audio, but not play it in the browser, correct?

Just add the muted parameter to the  that is playing back the media you are grabbing.

```
<video muted>

</video>
```

You can do this programmatically:

```
video.muted=true;
```

If you don't want to record audio - change your audio constraint to audio: false:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true, audio: false
        })
```

Comment: hello thank you so much for your helps. actually i tried your solution. but while i recording audio i don't want to hear my sound but same time i want to record it.

Comment: if you mute the video tag - you sill still record the audio.. it just will not play back. (options 1 &2)